# Unique Index on NULLable field isn't creating a Unique Constraint so I can make it a FK on another table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, unique-constraint

I'm in MS SQL 2016. I'm a bit confused. I have a field that I have put a unique index on. The DocID is not a primary key, but it will be unique (and is NULLable):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IX_Table_Unique_DocID]
ON [dbo].[Table]([DocID] ASC) 
WHERE [DocID] IS NOT NULL;
```

So when I am creating a new table that will reference DocID, I want to make it a FK.

`,constraint fk_Table2_DocID foreign key (DociD) references Table (DocID)`

However, I get the below error:

```
There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'Table' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'fk_Table2_DocID'.
```

What I am reading from MSDN shows that this is the way to create a UNIQUE constraint on a NULLable field. I am not finding anything that showing me other wise :/

Can someone point me in the right direction? I don't even mind if it's a "Here let me google that for you" link because I just can't seem to find it :)

Comment: You can create a foreign key that references a unique index but not a unique filtered index

Comment: The unique filtered index will functionally serve as a unique constraint to ensure no non-NULL duplicate `DocID` values. However, it doesn't seem SQL Server will allow a unique filtered index to be referenced by a foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server a foreign key constraint can be created between one *table* to another.

It requires a unique index on the referenced column.

This can be created by either `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX` or a constraint based unique index (`UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY`).

You are using `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX` but you also have a filter condition `WHERE [DocID] IS NOT NULL`

There is no facility to create a foreign key that references the *subset of the table* defined by a filtered index.

SQL Server would only allow one `NULL` `DocID` in a non filtered unique index. Presumably this is why you need the filtered index.

You would need another different table with all your distinct `DocID` - then you can put a non filtered unique index on that and reference that in foreign keys.

The only other way I can think of would be some kludgy workaround. For example if all legitimate `DocID` are positive integers you could assign unique negative integers to the ones where this is not applicable (instead of `NULL`) and then create a unique index on that.

`Table2` could then reference `Table1(DocID)` in a foreign key and additionally have a check constraint that `DocID > 0` to ensure it isn't referencing any of these bogus ids.